# Jquery detect if all typeable letter is pressed

Tags: jquery

I need to detect if user has pressed any which is typeable. (sorry for my English).

I have write down this code. However this code works but I need to know if this is good coding standard? Can I use this in live environment? Any improved solution?

```
jQuery('body').keydown(function (e) {
        if ((e.keyCode === 173 || e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 90) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 111) || (e.keyCode >= 189 && e.keyCode <= 192) || (e.keyCode >= 219 && e.keyCode <= 222)) {
        console.log('typed');
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's better on `keyup` than  `keydown`, but if it works why don't you use in a production environment?

Comment: Just need to know if this is good? As I am using so many condition. Maybe someone know a better solution? I tried searching but unable to find what I need. I do not know regular expression (maybe someone can make it)

Comment: Your code is fine. Regular expressions are not for this purposes. What pattern do you expect to target? The other technique is make an array of keys and then check if the pressed key is in the array. But in your case, this doesn't fit since you need ranges like `>= 48 && <= 90`, so your code is good.

Comment: You are welcome. See you soon :)